# how to deploy MVC project using file system to iis 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, web-deployment

Hi I would like to deploy my MVC internet application to my remote IIS 7 server. I published my app through VS2012 using file system option. I copied my published files to following location.

```
inetpub/wwwroot/applicationName
```

And I tried to access from my local computer but it only shows the files in the /applicationName folder.

1. How to display my application properly? I'm new to VS2012, am I missing something during deploy my app?
2. And If I choose global.ascx file it returns (404 - File or directory not found) error.

Comment: Have you converted your published folder into the Application? if not then go to IIS and Convert your folder into the Application.